# How can I close a second window (WIN32), and re-open it

Tags: c++, winapi

Im using DestroyWindow(HWND), but when I need to open again the same window, doesnt execute.
I already try with CloseWindow(HWND), but just minimizes de window.
This is what i have in the command Destroy

```
case WM_DESTROY: {
        DestroyWindow(contacts);
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Once destroyed, a window is gone for good, and it is not possible to "*open again the same window*". You'll need to explain in more detail what it is that you are trying to actually achieve.

Answer (score 2):

First, your code is invalid. WM_DESTROY is sent to the window *after* you (or someone else) have already called DestroyWindow().

You want to call this function in response to  WM_CLOSE instead. This destroys the window permanently.

Second, there is no reopening. Either hide/show (ShowWindow) or   recreate. Most probably all you need is ShowWindow with SW_HIDE/SW_SHOWNORMAL.

Comment: You are assuming that `contacts` is the window that is in the process of being closed/destroyed. I read the OP's example as `contacts` maybe being a child window instead. In which case, calling `DestroyWindow()` in response to `WM_DESTROY` is ok, albeit redundant since a parent/owner window automatically destroys its child/owned windows.